# How to publish specific files using Publish Build Artifact Task

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

I am Building C# Application using Visual Studio Build In Azure Pipeline.

My solution Contains multiple project (ManagerWeb & WebAPI).

I want to Publish Two Separate Artifact ManagerWeb & WebAPI respectively.

[image]
All the required File's are present in `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`.

How I can specify a pattern using which I can get Two Separate Artifact ?
Example All the File name with `WebAPI` in 1st Artifact & `ManagerWeb` in another.

The File name from ArtifactStaging Directory are as Below

```
Something.Manager.WebAPI.deploy.cmd
Something.Manager.WebAPI.deploy-readme.txt
Something.Manager.WebAPI.SetParameters.xml
Something.Manager.WebAPI.SourceManifest.xml
Something.Manager.WebAPI.zip

Something.ManagerWeb.deploy.cmd
Something.ManagerWeb.deploy-readme.txt
Something.ManagerWeb.SetParameters.xml
Something.ManagerWeb.SourceManifest.xml
Something.ManagerWeb.zip
```

Any Help will be appreciable.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a PowerShell task to create two folders and move the files to there:

```
cd $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
$files = dir
mkdir WebAPI
mkdir ManagerWeb
ForEach($file in $files)
{
   if($file.FullName.Contains("WebAPI"))
   {
       mv $file.FullName -Destination WebAPI
   }
   else
   {
       mv $file.FullName -Destination ManagerWeb
   }      
}
```

Then in the "Path to publish" field add the folders:

For WebApi artifacts:

```
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/WebAPI
```

And for ManagerWeb artifacts:

```
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/ManagerWeb
```

Comment: I Have All the Files into Single Folder i.e `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` As a reason I am facing Problem to publish it separately

Comment: Oh my mistake, in your file names I thought there are in 2 folders. so use the copy files like the second answer.

Comment: While Building the Solution only it get copied into Artifact Folder. I Can't Alter the Build Step it's as per project requirement. I am Looking for some pattern like `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.WirelineManager.*.*.*`

Comment: @Eddie Ok, so I updated my answer, a powershell script that put the files into 2 folders.

Comment: :- Adding PowerShell Script Task worked.. . . .Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Add two *Copy Files* steps which copy;

- ManagerWeb files to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\ManagerWeb`
- WebAPI files to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebAPI`

Then have two *Publish Artifact* steps to;

- Publish `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\ManagerWeb` as ManagerWeb
- Publish `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebAPI` as WebAPI

I've mocked this up and exported the YAML as follows;

```
pool:
  name: Hosted VS2017
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\ManagerWeb'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'your/path/here/ManagerWeb'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\ManagerWeb'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebAPI'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'your/path/here/WebAPI'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebAPI'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: ManagerWeb'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\ManagerWeb'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: WebAPI'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebAPI'
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.The Thing is I Have One Specific Solution Which contains Both this Project and As a Reason all the files are directly moving to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`

Comment: @Eddie could you add the YAML for your current _Copy Files_ step please.