# How do I share allure test report with stakeholders created with azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, protractor, allure

I have build a automation framework through protractor and build it on Azure Devops . In azure devops my automated test are running on linux server and allure test report is also getting stored there. 
Now I have a requirement to share it with stakeholders and peers through mail.

As allure api needs a server to host test reports . I don't want to host them on any server , I want to share them with mail . is it possible to do so?

Test Framework : Protractor 
Language : JS
Reporting : Allure reports
Project Management Tool : Azure Devops

Comment: Apart from sharing them with mail. If you just need to avoid to host them in server, how about storing them using Publish Artifact Task or hold them in Artifacts feed?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response , Could you please guide me how to do that .. as the reports are in form of html pages .

Comment: You can add [this task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) in your pipeline, specify where to find the html pages in that task. After run, you can find the published zip file(contains the html pages) in that run's **Summary**. Check if you can get useful info about this task from this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56377787/how-to-publish-specific-files-using-publish-build-artifact-task).

Comment: Or you can host them in [feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/feeds?view=azure-devops), then anyone that have access to your feed can download the package online. (It requires you to pack your file into package and publish the package in pipeline, there's several package types(nuget, maven,universal...) available, you can check which is more suitable...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this docker container and exporting an emailable report to send you by email. 
https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service#customize-emailable-report